# Invoking LAMMPS from commandline after a Homebrew Installation

Tags: macos, homebrew, lammps

I am trying to invoke the LAMMPS package from the terminal (OSX).

The documentation [here](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html#start-2-5) seems to indicate that under Mac OSX it will 'just work' and [here](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html#running-lammps) they are using the following command to interface to the library

```
$ lmp_linux
```

I installed the script with homebrew via this [minimalistic documentation](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html#homebrew) and I have checked the installation is correct. I feel that this is something someone more familiar with homebrew installations may be able to quickly answer

Comment: Is this a programmer question?

Comment: Yes, in the way that I am trying to establish an interface to a library.

Comment: I wonder if you should have defined an environment variable that links to the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brew info lammps
```

this will tell you where you installed the package. It appears as though you haven't "Made" the executable yet. [This](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html#start-2-1) page states that you need to navigate to your `src/` file (probably in `~/Documents/Lammps\ Turball/src/` or similar following your homebrew download).

Now in the `src/` folder in terminal type one of the following commands

```
make mpi
make serial
```

Read the docs though [here](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_start.html#start-2-1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To call LAMMPS just type in your terminal: lmp_mpi or lmp_serial.
To get further help just type lmp_mpi -h or lmp_serial -h.